# Python requests - Unable to imitate post request to scrape table data from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests

I'm attempting to scrape the table data from the website https://rss.knf.gov.pl/rss_pub/ using python requests.

From the browser devtools, I can see on page refresh (and also when selecting from the limit dropdown under the table) a post request is being sent to retrieve this data, which is returning it in a json. Which I can see in the 'Response' page of devtools.

However, when I try to imitate this request, The result is an empty json. The code I'm running is:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://rss.knf.gov.pl/rss_pub/'
}

payload = {
    "cmd":"get",
    "language":"en",
    "search":[],
    "limit":10,
    "offset":0,
    "method":"Default",
    "sort":[{"field":"HOLDER_FULL_NAME","direction":"asc"}],
    "searchLogic":"AND",
    "searchValue":""
}

url = 'https://rss.knf.gov.pl/rss_pub/'
s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)
s.get(url)
r = s.post(url+'JSON', json=payload)
```

And after running this code, I'm seeing only an empty json:

```
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.text
'{}'
```

Am I missing anything from my request causing this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data=` parameter instead of `json=`:

```py
import requests

url = "https://rss.knf.gov.pl/rss_pub/JSON"

payload = {
    "request": '{"cmd":"get","language":"pl","search":[],"limit":10000,"offset":0,"method":"Default","sort":[{"field":"HOLDER_FULL_NAME","direction":"asc"}],"searchLogic":"AND","searchValue":""}'
}

data = requests.post(url, data=payload).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "total": 9,
    "records": [
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "AQR Capital Management, LLC ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-09-08",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "CDPROJEKT",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-09-12",
            "ISIN": "PLOPTTC00011",
            "recid": 1,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.5",
        },
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "AQR Capital Management, LLC ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-10-23",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "ALLEGRO",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-10-24",
            "ISIN": "LU2237380790",
            "recid": 2,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.5",
        },
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "GSA Capital Partners LLP ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-07-07",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "TSGAMES",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-08-21",
            "ISIN": "PLTSQGM00016",
            "recid": 3,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.6",
        },
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "Insignis FIZ ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-01-13",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "GPW",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-08-21",
            "ISIN": "PLGPW0000017",
            "recid": 4,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.59",
        },
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "Marshall Wace LLP ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-10-24",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "KETY",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-10-25",
            "ISIN": "PLKETY000011",
            "recid": 5,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.78",
        },
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "Marshall Wace LLP ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-10-18",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "CDPROJEKT",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-10-19",
            "ISIN": "PLOPTTC00011",
            "recid": 6,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.72",
        },
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "Marshall Wace LLP ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-10-12",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "JSW",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-10-13",
            "ISIN": "PLJSW0000015",
            "recid": 7,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.71",
        },
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "PSquared Asset Management AG ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-10-17",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "LPP",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-10-18",
            "ISIN": "PLLPP0000011",
            "recid": 8,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.5",
        },
        {
            "HOLDER_FULL_NAME": "Silver Point Capital, L.P. ",
            "POSITION_DATE": "2023-10-24",
            "ISSUER_NAME": "CCC",
            "MODIFY_DATE": "2023-10-25",
            "ISIN": "PLCCC0000016",
            "recid": 9,
            "NET_SHORT_POSITION_O": "0.62",
        },
    ],
    "status": "success",
}
```